# Is there any alternative to the atom package line-diff-details?

Tags: git, atom-editor

It's a very useful package but it gives errors time to time. Is there any alternative package to review and revert line changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`git-diff-details`](https://atom.io/packages/git-diff-details) is an alternative. You could see if it's more reliable.